# UITableView params not inherited from IB

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, background-color

I have a TabBar app built in Xcode 4.2.1 using storyboards. The problem is that a UITableView is not reflecting changes I make in IB. For example: when I use IB to make changes to Background Color, Scroller visibility, separator color, there have no visible effect on the UITableView.

However, if I set these params programmatically, they work great. What am I missing? Some code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // get a pointer to our delegate. This is where the data will be stored
    // which gets passed between the Views (e.g. Favorites)
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self; 
//  myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    // this will suppress the separator lines between empty rows.
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    myTableView.tableFooterView = view;

    self.view = myTableView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: The above class extended ViewController. I changed it to extend UITableViewController and everything fell into place. The viewDidLoad() method is now greatly simplified because many of the things I was manually configuring are handled automatically by the UITableViewController class. I can now change the UITableView params in IB as expected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // during construction, call the super class's method FIRST. 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // get a pointer to our delegate. This is where the data will be stored
    // which gets passed between the Views (e.g. Favorites)
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // this will suppress the separator lines between empty rows.
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = view;
}
```